# How to Connect Virtualized PostgreSQL Client to Server on Phisical Machine?

Tags: client, postgresql-9.1

my first question posted here.

Right now I have my laptop with **Ubuntu 12.04** running **PostgreSQL 9.01** on the same machine I have a virtualized **Fedora 18** running under **VirtualBox 4.2.12**.

On this virtualized Fedora I have **PostgreSQL** client and want to connecto to the PostgreSQL server running on Ubuntu.

I have edited the file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` on the **Ubuntu** server to allow connections:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And also I'm editing the file /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf on the same Ubuntu to allow the user postgres to connec to the database test:

```
local   postgres        test        md5
```

But when I try to connect from the Fedora the following error message appears on PgAdmin3:

```
Access to database denied
The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.239", user "postgres", database "jpa", 
SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.239", user "postgres", 
database           "jpa", SSL off

To access a database on a PostgreSQL server, you first have to grant primary access 
to the server for your client (Host Based Authentication). 

PostgreSQL will check the pg_hba.conf file if a pattern that matches 
your client address / username / database is present and enabled before any 
SQL GRANT access control lists are evaluated.

The initial settings in pg_hba.conf are quite restrictive, in order to avoid 
unwanted security holes caused by unreviewed but mandatory system settings. 

You'll probably want to add something like host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5

This example grants MD5 encrypted password access to all databases to all users 
on the private network 192.168.0.0/24.
You can use the pg_hba.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III 
to edit the pg_hba.conf configuration file. 

After changing pg_hba.conf, you need to trigger a server configuration reload 
using pg_ctl or by stopping and restarting the server process.
```

My pg_hba.conf is:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             10.0.2.15/16            md5
#local   postgres        postgres        md5
#local   postgres        jpa        md5
#local   postgres        test        md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

And **10.0.2.15** it's the ip of the virtualized Fedora.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just try with:

```
host all all samenet md5
```

and

```
host all all samehost md5
```

on **pg_hba.conf** and both options worked!!

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads:

> no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.1.239"

That is true. So you should add something like this to your pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5
```

Additionally you have to `GRANT PRIVILIGES`

for example:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'%' identified by 'newpassword' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Actually the command to GRANT is: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE jpa TO postgres with grant option; but still no connection from the Fedora

Comment: I just try with: `host    all             all             samenet          md5` and `host    all             all             samehost          md5` on pg_hba.conf and both options worked!!

Comment: @Saija yes, using the hostname is even better than using the IP.